# geometry nodes curve array modifier with relative offset and differing instance sizes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: status]

I did a curve array modifier in geometry nodes with and float curve to differ the sizes along a curve, everything works perfektly fine. But i really want to apply a feature to make the offset realtive to each other, so even if the size of every instance changes the distance to each arrayed piece stays the same.

I havent been using geometry nodes for a long time, so any help is appreciated.